# How to create events and proper use of event handlers for a button click C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, delegates

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm trying to create a Hangman game in WinForms, I've got the game functionality working, but I'm trying to create a form where the user selects a category and then the word to guess is from the category selected.
I've got a HangEventArgs like below:

```
public class HangEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Category WordCategory { get; set; }
}
```

and a class for the data (I'm hoping to expand it to add more features in the future).

```
public enum Category
{
    // Categories are stores here
}

public class HangData
{
    public Category WordCategory { get; protected set; }

    public HangData(Category askWhat)
    {
        WordCategory = askWhat;
    }
}
```

And a class where the words are stored

```
public static class WordsToGuess
{
    public static string[] Capitals =
    {
        "London",
        "Paris" // more words here
    }; // more categories here
```

Finally I have my button click event for all the categories, I've created my own Button as to not use the default EventArgs.

```
private void bCategory_Click(object sender, HangEventArgs e)
{
    MainGame mg = new MainGame(new HangData(e.WordCategory));
    mg.ShowDialog();
}
```

I've been trying to use event handlers like so

```
public event EventHandler<HangEventArgs>(object sender, HangEventArgs e);
```

But I'm not sure the proper way to implement this into my code.
If I use

```
bCapitals.Click += new EventHandler(bCategory_Click);
```

I get a no overload matches delegate error and I'm stuck on how to fix it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Is your HangEventArgs class derived from EventArgs? Is there a perticular reason you can't use the default event args for button clicks?

Comment: also bCapitals.Click += new EventHandler(bCategory_Click); should maybe be bCategory.Click += new EventHandler(bCategory_Click); seems like you might be bounding the wrong button

Answer (score 2):

Create your category button like this:

```
public class CategoryButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Just discard the `e` argument and pass your own argument.
        base.OnClick(new HangEventArgs { WordCategory = Category.Cities });
    }
}
```

Subscribe the event with:

```
categoryButton1.Click += CategoryButton1_Click;
```

Use like this

```
private void CategoryButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e is HangEventArgs hangEventArgs) {
        MessageBox.Show(hangEventArgs.WordCategory.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that the click mechanism still works as expected. You don't need to fire the event yourself.

---

Of course you could create your own event; however, then, it must have a different name like `HangClick` and you must fire it yourself.

```
public class CategoryButton : Button
{
    public event EventHandler<HangEventArgs> HangClick;

    protected virtual void OnHangClick(HangEventArgs e)
    {
        HangClick?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnHangClick(new HangEventArgs { WordCategory = Category.Cities });

        // Optionally, if you want to preserve the standard click event behaviour:
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Subscribe with:

```
categoryButton1.HangClick += CategoryButton1_HangClick;
```

Use like this:

```
private void CategoryButton1_HangClick(object sender, HangEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.WordCategory.ToString());
}
```